# Angular - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'showSpinner')

Tags: angular

When I try to execute this block of code this is what I get.

> core.mjs:6485 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot
> read properties of undefined (reading 'showSpinner')

```
 async ShowData() {
  if(this.loading) {
    return;
  }

 this.loading = true;
 this.detailApp.showSpinner('Show Spinner');
 try {
    this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged()
      ).subscribe(async changes =>{
        await this.LandComponent.getAllData(changes.textName).then(data =>{
      this.preview = data;
      this.activePageDataChunk = this.preview.slice(0,this.pageSize);

    }).catch(error =>{
      console.log(error)
    })
  });
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
  this.loading = false;
  this.detailApp.hideSpinner();
}
```

// detailApp.ts

```
export interface detailApp {
showSpinner(text:string):void
}
```

Comment: the error means that `this.detailApp` does not have a method called `showSpinner`

Comment: there is already method `showSpinner` in `this.detailApp`

Comment: Where do you inizialize the `detailApp` variable? You probably need something like `this.detailApp = new detailApp();` Or better of an implementation of `detailApp` as interfaces can not be instanciated. Also classes and interfaces shoud start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that `this.detailApp` is not initialized anywhere in the file, so it is `undefined`